# Ubuntu / Lenovo yoga Wifi issues

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu: 14.10, Kernel: 3.16.0-31-generic. I have some network problems. My Laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 13. I had some issues getting the network adapter to work, but it works now - sometimes! Here is what happens:

At work, everything works like a charm. I have had no problems what so ever!

At home, Wifi connection shows a "?" in the toolbar.
Everything using the network connection stops responding. For example the file browser, when I try to connect to something using SSH, my Bluefish editor, also using SSH. When I try to edit network setting, it also stops responding. I have to force quit these applications... 
"“Settings” is not responding.
You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the application to quit entirely."

The browser is working for a while, but then it looses connection. However the browser does not stop responding, it just looses connection.

If I try to reboot, the system freezes completely.

On my other devices there is no problems connecting to this network.

Some commands, with information:

```
nm-tool:
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [1gbitinternet 1] ---------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723au
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        2C:D0:5A:F3:72:E2

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes



rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.4
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 2c:d0:5a:f3:72:e2
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723au driverversion=3.16.0-31-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.45 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn



lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:029c Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:000a Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5571 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Fit
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


modinfo rtl8723au
modinfo: ERROR: Module rtl8723au not found.

sudo rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no


git log -n 1 --oneline
bd3ef04 rtl8723au: Allow build on armv7l
```

Maybe the wrong driver is enabled?

```
sudo modinfo 8723au
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8723au.ko
version:        v4.1.6_7336.20130426
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     4F10D2E0FAC6F67FFD05DE4
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0724d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp1724d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8724d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_regulatory_id:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_cbw40_enable:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_btcoex_enable:Enable BT co-existence mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (1-9) (default 1) (int)
```

I still have these errors:

```
dmesg | grep -e 8723 -e 80211 | tail -n15
[   11.540092] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   11.540094] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.540095] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.540097] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   11.540098] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[   11.540099] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.626988] RTL8723AU: ERROR send eapol packet
[   11.639382] RTL8723AU: ERROR send eapol packet
[   11.639679] RTL8723AU: ERROR set pairwise key to hw: alg:4(WEP40-1 WEP104-5 TKIP-2 AES-4) camid:4
[  325.669099] RTL8723AU: ERROR set ssid [1gbitinternet] fw_state = 0x00000008
[  325.773209] RTL8723AU: ERROR start auth
[  325.776061] RTL8723AU: ERROR auth success, start assoc
[  325.801791] RTL8723AU: ERROR send eapol packet
[  325.828360] RTL8723AU: ERROR send eapol packet
[  325.829611] RTL8723AU: ERROR set pairwise key to hw: alg:4(WEP40-1 WEP104-5 TKIP-2 AES-4) camid:4
```

Comment: I am now using my HTC one as wifi hotspot, and now there is no problems what so ever. But as soon as i connect to my router, the problems start over...

Comment: I already did follow the instructions above, so i should have the correct driver. nm-tool says the driver is "rtl8723au"

Comment: If the answers of the supposed duplicate questions don't help, please run the generic [WiFi diagnostics](/q/425155) and include a link to the results in your question. The version of the kernel module (`modinfo rtl8723au`) or better yet the revision of the git repository (`git log -n 1 --oneline`) could come in handy too.

Comment: I added more info. 
So if I get this right, it seems like the driver I downloaded, does not load? If this is correct, do you know how I fix it?

Comment: For some reason, it now seems to work! Earlier, I followed this guide (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262693) - but it did not solve the problem. Today i tried again, and now it works! I did one thing different though, I blacklisted "r8723au" instead of "8723au". I did the same thing a few days ago, with no luck. But now it did the trick!

The errors from dmesg persists - but the wifi works.

Comment: I still use full power-off to fix this issue that comes only after *reboot*. See this link for details: http://askubuntu.com/a/697725