# 15.10 Slow network speed on Yoga 13 ( first gen) Realtek nic

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, 15.10, realtek-wireless

My download and upload speeds are down to .5 mbps and 1 mbps respectively.    They should be around 43mI just installed 15.10 on a first gen yoga 13.

I've tried swapping drivers and steps from this article: http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/

No success.

Any guidance would be appreciated in troubleshooting this.

The network card is a Realtec rtl8723au:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Nov 2015 08:39 EST -0500

Booted last: 10 Nov 2015 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-17-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 19:56:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 004: ID 04f2:b322 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments Invensense Embedded MotionApp HID Sensor
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 04f3:000a Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8723AU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 0d8c:0006 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Storm HP-USB500 5.1 Headset
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 067b:2305 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2305 Parallel Port
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0b95:7720 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0409:0059 NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0409:0059 NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              548864  1 r8723au
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  0
video                  36864  2 i915,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enx00505b04bdc5 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enx00505b04bdc5' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlx2016d810535b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlx2016d810535b' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.16  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlx2016d810535b' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1280  Metric:1
          RX packets:68821 errors:0 dropped:544 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:63906 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:67449418 (67.4 MB)  TX bytes:25194957 (25.1 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enx00505b04bdc5  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx2016d810535b  IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"NETGEAR25"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'NETGEAR25' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=12 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlx2016d810535b
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlx2016d810535b
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx2016d810535b

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       798     1  0 Nov09 ?        00:00:18 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx2016d810535b
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        802.11n WLAN Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723au
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlx2016d810535b' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.4/3-1.4:1.2/net/wlx2016d810535b
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlx2016d810535b
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     NETGEAR25
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       a335c441-86a3-4bff-82b0-a70bedd88d16
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     150 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   a335c441-86a3-4bff-82b0-a70bedd88d16 | NETGEAR25
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.16/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        expiry = 1447246421
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.16
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'wlx2016d810535b' [IF]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx00505b04bdc5
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         ASIX Elec. Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AX88772 
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         asix
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Dec-2011
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx00505b04bdc5' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2.1/3-1.2.1.1/3-1.2.1.1:1.0/net/enx00505b04bdc5
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID                   BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
NETGEAR25              <MAC 'NETGEAR25' [AC1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       yes     * 
sky n gus              <MAC 'sky n gus' [AC6]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WEP        no        
ATT680                 <MAC 'ATT680' [AC5]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
--                     <MAC '--' [AN4]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
HOME-B368              <MAC 'HOME-B368' [AC3]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
xfinitywifi            <MAC 'xfinitywifi' [AN6]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  --         no        
--                     <MAC '--' [AN7]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2       no        
fashionmadness         <MAC 'fashionmadness' [AN8]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        
xfinitywifi            <MAC 'xfinitywifi' [AN9]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  --         no        
--                     <MAC '' [AC4]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
--                     <MAC '--' [AN11]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Library of Alexandria  <MAC 'Library of Alexandria' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
baseball               <MAC 'baseball' [AN13]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1       no        
--                     <MAC '\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00' [AC7]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2       no        
HOME-E7BE              <MAC 'HOME-E7BE' [AN15]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        
xfinitywifi            <MAC 'xfinitywifi' [AC8]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  --         no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR25]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR25 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlx2016d810535b' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=NETGEAR25
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enx00505b04bdc5  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlx2016d810535b  32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

enx00505b04bdc5  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      3   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlx2016d810535b  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'NETGEAR25' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETGEAR25"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c88686921
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Library of Alexandria' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Library of Alexandria"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c8b768eed
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'HOME-B368' [AC3]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"HOME-B368"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c89014169
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC '' [AC4]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c89014b5a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'ATT680' [AC5]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ATT680"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000034790669
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'sky n gus' [AC6]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"sky n gus"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000002f96ee46565
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC '\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00' [AC7]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c7e72245f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC 'xfinitywifi' [AC8]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"xfinitywifi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c7e722b6e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-17-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     1F1A25B2E9C847110BD9ED9
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        8A:A8:7E:56:80:81:D5:83:A1:82:B3:AF:48:3C:67:E7:4C:E0:9F:4E
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[    9.043610] rtl8723au 3-1.4:1.2 wlx2016d810535b: renamed from wlan0
[    9.261442] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx2016d810535b: link is not ready
[    9.331654] rtl8723au: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B.bin
[    9.849921] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx2016d810535b: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)
[   10.549926] asix 3-1.2.1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'asix' at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2.1.1, ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet, <MAC 'enx00505b04bdc5' [IF]>
[   10.552149] asix 3-1.2.1.1:1.0 enx00505b04bdc5: renamed from eth0
[   10.574751] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00505b04bdc5: link is not ready
[   10.576961] asix 3-1.2.1.1:1.0 enx00505b04bdc5: link down
[   10.578257] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00505b04bdc5: link is not ready
[   11.330157] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx2016d810535b: link becomes ready
[ 1310.905233] Error: Driver 'rtl8723au' is already registered, aborting... (repeated 3 times)
[ 1747.568148] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx2016d810535b: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 1747.568973] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00505b04bdc5: link is not ready
[ 1747.569740] asix 3-1.2.1.1:1.0 enx00505b04bdc5: link down
[ 1747.571165] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00505b04bdc5: link is not ready
[ 1747.611391] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx2016d810535b: link is not ready
[ 1747.682975] rtl8723au: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B.bin
[ 1749.457435] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx2016d810535b: link becomes ready
[35174.297977] Error: Driver 'rtl8723au' is already registered, aborting...

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of full power cycles fixed it for me (powering all the way down! Not rebooting/resetarting).  Reboots did not solve my issue.

The driver I was having issues with was the original driver for this wireless card provided by Larry Finger (and added to the Linux kernel).  Jes Sorensen, the current driver maintainer, says that the driver may not be powering up the chip correctly/ it may not fully know the correct power sequence.

The current maintainer says you can try his new driver rtl8xxxu.  It isn't yet part of a linux release that I am aware, but he gave me a link to his Kernel fork if you want to compile it and give it a try: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/jes/linux.git/log/?h=rtl8723au-mac80211 ( you can see in the log he added the rtl8xxxu on 10/14/2015 )  It should be in one of the upcoming releases.

I'm too lazy to compile a kernel and I am just going with power cycles when my network speed drops.